# django_session table killing my MySQL server and django app

Tags: mysql, python, django

I need your help
I hav a Django app that is about 7 years old and have been degrading now..every time the website goes down and back up and the issue is with mysql server

Usually i need to just restart mysql server and it comes back up..i have been doing this for 2 years now and am ready to fix the issue once and for all and need your help to do this

Here is screenshot of the database tables
[image]

The `django_session` tables has **`3,512,729,600`** data Length and **`24,152,301`** rows
I am guessing this is where the issue is coming from and why the website just dies sometimes when mysql can not handle the query and several timeouts that kills the app. If it is something else then please enlighten me.

Anyways i tried deleting the `django_session` table but with no luck
I get the following errors

> Error in query (1451): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`font_database`.`fonts_fontfile`, CONSTRAINT
>   `session_id_refs_session_key_37e5d4124e1e319f` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`session_id`) REFERENCES `django_session` (`session_key`))

What do i do here?
Need serious help here

MySQL version is 5.7.23

**If you need any more information please ask me and i will try to add it to this question.**

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Just noticed that issue is with total number of connections on the MySQL server is maxed out at 152

```
mysql> show status where `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| Threads_connected | 152   |
+-------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.74 sec)
```

Also when i check the connections they are all from the django_sessions which is why when i restart server it works fine but then gets back to same issue as the sessions table is just too high and too many rows

```
mysql> show processlist;
+------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+---------+------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id   | User               | Host      | db                 | Command | Time | State        | Info                                                                                               |
+------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+---------+------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 3709 | font_database | localhost | font_database | Query   | 3164 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2019-02-23 13:00:37' |
| 3710 | font_database | localhost | font_database | Query   | 3162 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2019-02-23 13:00:39' |
| 3711 | font_database | localhost | font_database | Query   | 3161 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2019-02-23 13:00:41' |
| 3714 | font_database | localhost | font_database | Query   | 3133 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2019-02-23 13:01:09' |
| 3716 | font_database | localhost | font_database | Query   | 3131 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2019-02-23 13:01:11' |
| 3717 | font_database | localhost | font_database | Query   | 3129 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2019-02-23 13:01:13' |
...
...
till maxed to 152 connections
```

> Again if you need any additional information, ask and i will provide
>   it. This is all i believe can help give idea of what issue is

---

**UPDATE:** (from request in comments)

> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM django_session WHERE
>   django_session.last_login >= '2019-02-23 13:00:37'

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  django_session  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    24200442    33.33   Using where
```

> SHOW CREATE TABLE django_session

```
Table   Create Table
django_session  CREATE TABLE `django_session` (
  `session_key` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `session_data` longtext NOT NULL,
  `expire_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_key`),
  KEY `django_session_c25c2c28` (`expire_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

---

**UPDATE v2:** (after running `ALTER TABLE django_session ADD KEY (last_login)`)

> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM django_session WHERE
>   django_session.last_login >= '2019-03-04 13:00:37'

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  django_session  NULL    range   last_login  last_login  5   NULL    1   100.00  Using where; Using index
```

Comment: The problem is that `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM django_session WHERE django_session.last_login >= '2019-02-23 13:00:37'` is a slow query. Please show `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM django_session WHERE django_session.last_login >= '2019-02-23 13:00:37'` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE django_session`

Comment: Please post TEXT data requested by danblack on Feb 25, 19 at 22:04 plus results of SHOW INDEX FROM django_session;  Thanks

Comment: i have updated question with output of the SQL commands at bottom of the post/question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM django_session WHERE django_session.last_login >= '2019-02-23 13:00:37'` is a slow query. Your process list is showing this taking 3133 seconds so far and hasn't completed.

If there was an index on the `last_login` column in django_session this would likely be quicker.

```
ALTER TABLE django_session ADD KEY (last_login)
```

You should also check what this query is providing within django. It seems like a rather meaningless number.

I'd suspect 2M rows is probably covering old data and probably can be deleted. Try the clearing method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296159/django-session-database-table-cleanup).

Recommend clearing at least some rows before adding an index.

Comment: i have updated question with output of the SQL commands at bottom of the post/question...i am not really sure what those do but i am open to share privately with you more details about the project and pay for your time..but anyways what will be the reason to add index to `last_login`?

Comment: The `SHOW CREATE TABLE` shows the table structure and the `EXPLAIN` showed how the query is executed. Type `ALL` means that it needs to examine the entire table to delete entries.  Added the `KEY` like the `ALTER TABLE...` part of this  answer says will enable MySQL to find the old `last_login` entries quicker. I'm not interesting in a job or a detailed involvement in this question like many SO/DBA helpers. Minor clarification questions can be asked however the answer is here.

Comment: the real issue is with the total number of connections which it is maxing out...even if i increase it it will still max out..so how can i solve that issue? seems the app is doing things wrong in logic..not sure why it keeps that many connection when it is only one app connecting to it. that is what i need help with. because the connections issue is why the app goes down all the time

Comment: By making these queries really quick, they won't be clogging the maximum number of connections. Occasionally connections will be phantoms due to web pages going away. These normally get timed out before they are exhausted.

Comment: so what do i need to do again? kind of lost sight on what i need to do? truncate table or sun the alter command?

Comment: a) do the alter table. b) work out why this query exists and if it has business value.

Comment: will do (a) now..(b) am sure you can help with that in few minutes if we discuss privately as i will provide a few very useful information i cant put in public. Aso i am not sure (b) because am not the developer that made the app...i paid someone to make the app several years back..although i know a little django am not good enough to figure out exactly if i need it or not but i can easily learn with a few direction from someone experienced with django

Comment: (b) No. Seek professional help.

Comment: i ran the `ALTER TABLE django_session ADD KEY (last_login)` but how can i confirm this ran successfully? took couple of minutes to complete but how can i check it was successful?

Comment: Does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` show the same queries taking a long time? Does `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM django_session WHERE django_session.last_login >= '2019-03-04 13:00:37'`  show it using an index? If you run the query how long does it take?

Comment: now the number of connections is much reduced to like 6 to 9 and `SHOW PROCESSLIST` is showing connections for the number of connections...also i still see the alter table command running in the process lists...seems it is very long running comman...5743 seconds and still going

Comment: i updated at bottom output of EXPLAIN statement...the thing is the website is still dying back and forth...maybe when the ALTER command completes it will be fine..but website still going down back and forth still currently...when i run query commands you provided SHOW and EXPLAIN..they return pretty quickly in less than 1 second

Comment: ok updated again...`ALTER` command finally completed and the EXPLAIN shows it is using index...EXPLAIN query took milliseconds to complete...connections dropped to fewer number now...so will keep watching and see

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you up and running. Please confirm this by accepting the answer. Its the least you could do after requiring every question to be answered twice.

Comment: so far the website is now responding well and havent seen it go down...thanks a million times!

Comment: @uberrebu Glad you made significant progress.  Keep up the good work in following guidance from danblack.  Disclaimer: I am the author of the website mentioned in view profile, Network profile.  When you want to work on threads_connected reduction get in touch.